# How do you decrement a number sequence in a specific pattern?

Tags: assembly, irvine32

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
   array DWORD  8 DUP(?)
   value DWORD  1
   currentNum DWORD  8

.code
main PROC
   call  Clrscr
   mov esi, OFFSET array
   mov ecx, 8
   call NumSequence
   exit
main ENDP

NumSequence PROC USES ecx edx esi

R1: 
    mov eax, value
    call WriteDec
    cmp currentNum, 1
    je R4
    JMP R2

R2: add eax, value
    call WriteDec
    cmp eax, CurrentNum
    je R3
    JMP R2

R3: 
    dec CurrentNum
    call Crlf
    JMP R1

R4:
    exit

NumSequence ENDP

END main
```

How do I decrement a number sequence in this pattern?

My code currently decrements the sequence the other way so the last number is 1 rather than 8.

1. 12345678
2. 2345678
3. 345678
4. 45678
5. 5678
6. 678
7. 78
8. 8

Comment: Sorry if the formatting is bad. It wouldn't let me put the code under my explanation.

Comment: Instead of `dec CurrentNum` you want `inc value` and instead of `cmp currentNum, 1` you want `cmp value, 8` and instead of `add eax, value` you want `add eax, 1` (since the steps are 1 in any case).

Answer (score 1):

*value* and *currentNum* are very ambiguous names. They don't reflect what you try to accomplish. Given the output that you desire, *startNum* and *stopNum* would be better choices.

Also there's no need to have a separate use of *WriteDec* for the first number on the list. Unless of course you want to display that single digit line number that your current program is **not** trying to output.

```
startNum DWORD 1
stopNum  DWORD 8
    ...
    mov  eax, startNum
R2: call WriteDec
    inc  eax
    cmp  eax, stopNum
    jbe  R2
    call Crlf
    inc  startNum
    mov  eax, startNum
    cmp  eax, stopNum
    jbe  R2
```

It is usually best to prefer register-based variables over memory-based variables. And seeing that *stopNum* will remain fixed at **8**, you can dismiss that one already. In below code I have placed *startNum* in the EBX register.

```
    mov  ebx, 1           ; startNum = 1
R1: mov  eax, ebx
R2: call WriteDec
    inc  eax
    cmp  eax, 8           ; stopNum == 8
    jbe  R2
    call Crlf
    inc  ebx              ; startNum++
    cmp  ebx, 8           ; stopNum == 8
    jbe  R1
```